# Show that $\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables defined on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$. Assume that $E[X_i]=0$, $E[X_i^2]=1$, and $E[X_iX_j]=0$ for all $i\neq j$ and $i\ge 1$. Let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$. Show that

1. for $\alpha>1$, $\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\to 0$ a.s.
2. for $\alpha>1/2$, $\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\to 0$ in probability.

---

My proof is that

1. Since we have $E[S_n^2]=n$, then by Markov's inequality
   $$
   P\left(\Big|\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\Big|\ge n^{-0.5(\alpha-1)}\right)\le n^{-(\alpha-1)} E|n^{-\alpha}S_n|^2=n^{-\alpha}.
   $$
   Then for $\alpha>1$,
   $$
   \sum _{n=1}^\infty P\left(\Big|\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\Big|\ge n^{-0.5(\alpha-1)}\right)<\infty
   $$
   By Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we proved our result in 1.
2. By Markov's inequality, for $\epsilon>0$,
   $$
   P\left(\Big|\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\Big|\ge \epsilon\right)\le \epsilon^{-2} E\left[\Big|\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\Big|^2\right]=\epsilon^{-2} n^{2\alpha-1}
   $$
   So as $n\to \infty$, $\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha}\to 0$ in probability.

Does this proof look good?

Comment: I think using Chebyshev's inequality in (2) is a bit more elegant, since the $X_i$ are uncorrelated. So you can use that $\mathbb{V}[S_n]=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}[X_i]$.

Comment: Other than that there is a small typo, in (2) it says $\epsilon^{-2}n^{2\alpha-1}$, but is has to be $\epsilon^{-2}n^{-2\alpha+1}$.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Yes, that should be Chebyshev's inequality,

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Yes!